# open mapping theorem problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question I need your help.

Let $f$ be an analytic on $U=D(z_0,R)\setminus{z_0}$ such that $z_0$ is a pole of $f$. Prove that for any $r\in (0,R)$ there is $m \in (0,\infty)$ such that $f(D(z_0,r)\setminus{z_0})\supset\{z:|z|>m\}$.

I could not really think of how to solve the problem but Since $f$ is analytic everywhere on $U$, except for $z_0$, $f$ is not constant and by open mapping theorem $f(U)$ is going to be open. But as I said i really need your help to solve this problem.

can you also send me link of some useful websites to help me understand better open mapping theorem.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hint: $1/f(z)$.

Comment: @daniel:I am sorry but it does not help me can you be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic in $D(z_0,R)\setminus \{z_0\}$ and $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, then there is a positive integer $k$ (the order of the pole), and a holomorphic $h \colon D(z_0,R) \to \mathbb{C}$ with $h(z_0) \neq 0$, such that

$$f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$$

on $D(z_0,R)\setminus\{z_0\}$. If $0 < R_1 \leqslant R$ is so small that $h$ has no zeros on $D(z_0,R_1)$, then we can on $D(z_0,R_1)$ consider the holomorphic function

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)} = (z-z_0)^k\cdot\frac{1}{h(z)}.$$

Then $g$ is a nonconstant holomorphic function on $D(z_0,R_1)$, with $g(z_0) = 0$.

For $0 < r \leqslant R_1$, what does that imply about the image $g(D(z_0,r))$, and how does the desired result for $f(D(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\})$ follow from that?